# Erro utilizando async no NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, async

Estou com um sistema em NodeJS em desenvolvimento e finalizei uma etapa, com a finalidade de testar, coloquei ele em um servidor e à partir disso começou a me retornar erro em todas as linhas do código em que utilizei as funções async.

**Erro:**

```
async index(request, response){
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
...
```

**Código:**

```
const Authentication = require('./AdminAuthController');
module.exports = {
async index(request, response){ // esta é a linha do erro
    const { admin } = request.headers;
    const auth = await(Authentication.checkAuthentication(admin));
    return response.json(auth);
}
```

Meu maior problema é encontrar o motivo de retornar este erro, sendo que, nos testes que fiz no localhost, todas as requisições funcionavam normalmente.

Comment: porque não faz `module.export =async index(request, response){
    const { admin } = request.headers;
    const auth = await(Authentication.checkAuthentication(admin));
    return response.json(auth);
}`, você está exportando um objeto e não uma função.

Comment: Abaixo há outras funções

Comment: Provavelmente é um problema de versão. Qual é a versão do Node.js que você usa no seu computador local e qual a versão do Node do servidor?

Comment: Acho que este é o problema mesmo. Meu computador está com a versão > 10.1 e no servidor está 6.1

Comment: https://medium.com/balta-io/nodejs-async-await-21ca3636252a Victor atualize para 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é a versão do Node.js que você está rodando no seu servidor. Recursos como o `async`/`await` entraram a partir do Node.js `7.6`. Desse modo, já que você está utilizando a versão `6`, esses recursos ainda não foram implementados, o que causa o erro de sintaxe.

Em virtude disso, sugiro que você atualize para alguma versão **LTS** posterior à versão `7.6`, como o Node.js `8` ou `10`.

É importante salientar que é sempre bom utilizar uma versão LTS em um ambiente de produção. Para saber mais sobre o esquema de versões do Node.js e entender o porquê disso, veja [este documento](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/).